# Angular + Websockets + data rendering

Tags: javascript, angularjs, websocket

I have application with Websockets using. 
On server changing some data, after i get some message from websocket what was changed and need update data in table. I get data from websocket, send GET request for getting data, and update my scope with data, but i don't see changes in table.
In **$scope.ordersList** i save date geted from server.

My websockets service:

```
var services = angular.module('services', []);
services.factory('EventService', ['$cookies',
    function($cookies) {
        var service = {};
        service.connect = function() {
            if (service.ws) {
                return;
            }
            var ws = new WebSocket("ws://" + window.location.host + "/events/");

            ws.onopen = function() {
                ws.send(JSON.stringify({
                    type: "auth",
                    token: $cookies.token
                }));
                console.log("Succeeded to open a conection");
            };
            ws.onerror = function() {
                console.log("Failed to open a connection");
            };
            ws.onmessage = function(message) {
                var obj = JSON.parse(message.data);
                if (obj.result) return;

                if (obj.id) {
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        service.callback(obj);
                    }, 1000)
                }
            };
            service.ws = ws;
        };
        service.subscribe = function(callback) {
            service.callback = callback;
        };
        return service;
    }
]);
```

How i use it in my controller:

```
EventService.subscribe(function(msg) {

            console.log('msg', msg);
            var item = $.grep($scope.ordersList, function(item) {
                return item.id == msg.id
            })
            if (item.length > 0) {
                item[0].status = msg.status
            } else {
                $scope.ordersList.push(msg);
            }

            $scope.$apply();

        });
        $scope.getOrders();
        EventService.connect();
```

And my template:

```
<tr item="parameter" ng-repeat="item in ordersList">
<td>{{item.id}}</td>
<td>{{item.symbol}}</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap the service.callback in a $rootScope.apply to get it into angulars digest cycle. Check this to get the concept: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/frameworks/angular-websockets/